How to show rich content in dialogflow in same line?
I was expecting all the rich messages I added in form of chips in dialogflow to be in same line (i mean 4-5 in one then in other) but it displayed only one in one line). How to solve this?
I tried it on dialogflow rich text bot i.e. the one having df-messenger and the chips are so many that user has to scroll to go to answer he expected
